# Facing issue with code signing with CI/CD

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, digital-signature, code-signing-certificate, digicert

I got struck somewhere, actually recently got a code signing certificate from DigiCert. They have given us a “crt” format certificate, previously we were using pfx format certificate. Now the thing is we were able to do the manual signing with the new certificate using SignTool.exe,
[signing with sign tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w09pA.png)
[It will ask for password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gKDt.png)

This is the powershell code I've used, with the commented lines we were able to sign in before.

$signtool = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.16299.0\x64\signtool.exe"
if (!(Test-Path "$signtool")) {
$signtool = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce\SignTool\signtool.exe"
}
Write-Host "Signtool path: $signtool"

```
#$pfxpassword = "************"
$pfxpassword = "************"

#Remove Zipping code from line 31-34 once above line is enabled
$packageName = $kpi.Value
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Smcty_Latest_Packages" -Filter "$packageName*.zip" -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    $zipFilePath = "C:\Smcty_Latest_Packages\$packageName*.zip"
    Expand-Archive -Path $zipFilePath -DestinationPath $destinationFolder -Force
    #TO DO digtal signing to the all smcty dlls of service project
    $dllFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationFolder -Filter "*smcty*.dll" -Recurse
    foreach ($dll in $dllFiles) {
        #& $signtool sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /f "..\Certificate\HTS.pfx" /p $pfxpassword $dll.FullName
        & $signtool sign /tr http://timestamp.digicert.com /td sha256 /f "C:\Certs2\************_international_s__rl.crt" /p $pfxpassword $dll.FullName
    }
```

}

```
if (Test-path("$destinationFolder\appsettings.development.json")) {
    Write-Host "Removing appsettings.json files from $destinationFolder"
    Get-ChildItem -Path $destinationFolder -Recurse -Filter "appsettings*.json" -Exclude "appsettings.development.json" | Remove-Item

    Write-Host "Replacing correct appsettings.json file in $destinationFolder"
    Rename-Item -Path "$destinationFolder\appsettings.development.json" "appsettings.json"
}
```

but when we try to implement that in pipeline the signature is not happening.
we are getting this error (SignTool Error: No certificates were found that met all the given criteria.)
Can anyone help me here with the exact syntax. Thanks in advance (We got one zip file with 3 certs and usb token from DigiCert). [we tried this systax too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNKVN.png).

Note: The DigiCert support team is telling not to convert from crt to pfx.

expecting the powershell code or syntax which I can implemnet in pipeline.

Comment: Check out this new code signing requirement from 1 June 2023 - it may explain the issue. https://knowledge.digicert.com/general-information/new-private-key-storage-requirement-for-standard-code-signing-certificates-november-2022 We found that the error related to the fact that that there was no private key included in the certificates. IF you use the sign tool with the /debug option you can see that it excludes the cert based on this criteria.